# curl php i need to read

Tags: php, json, curl

```
Array
(
    [result] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uniq] => 123456789
                    [name] => rig2
                    [description] => rig2

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [uniq] => 987654321
                    [name] => rig1
                    [description] => rig1

                )

        )

)
```

Plese give me exsample how to echo(print) only  [uniq] in php ?

Comment: This is a simple process of reading through an array with foreach which is basic PHP

Comment: use `foreach` loop

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)
 **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write it for you**

Comment: There are multiple instances of the `uniq` key, one in each of the arrays under `data`. Which one are you trying to get? The first one? All of them?

Comment: Pro tip: we're a bit different on Stack Overflow from other sources of help on the internet. 
Beginners are welcome, but we expect a certain amount of effort to be expended on a question prior to a question being posted. 
That is undoubtedly more time and effort for question authors, but it helps the community by ensuring that easily researched 
and/or duplicate questions are asked less often.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_column](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function to take out all the values corresponding to `[uniq]` key.

```
$uniq_values = array_column($input_array['data'], 'uniq');
print_r($uniq_values); // print them out
```

From [documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

> array_column() returns the values from a single column of the input,
>   identified by the column_key.
>
> **input** is A multi-dimensional array or an array of objects from which to pull a column of values from. If an array of objects is
>   provided, then public properties can be directly pulled. In order for
>   protected or private properties to be pulled, the class must implement
>   both the __get() and __isset() magic methods.
>
> **column_key** is The column of values to return. This value may be an integer key of the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for an associative array or property name. It may also be NULL to return complete arrays or objects.